# How to distinguish data types in a string with C on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, string, function, passwords

I'm writing a simple program that verifies an a 8 character password with a minimum of two numbers. This seems to be commonly assigned to beginners, but I could not find any answers to my question anywhere online and failed the assignment, but I would still like to learn how to do this and think this would be of help to other beginners like me

**I need to verify that a string containing both letters and numbers contains at least two numbers.**

isalpha() or isdigit() only read one character at a time, and strspn( , ) or strcspn() stop calculating length when it gets to a byte not found in the other segment, so if I input a password like "a1b2c3" using either one of those functions, the output will be 1 or 0.
I have also tried switching up the data types from char to int and vice versa.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {

   char password[8];              
   char numVerify[] = "1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9";
   int valid = 10

  do {
       printf("Enter Password: \n");
       scanf("%s",password);
       int a = strspn(password,numVerify);

     if (strlen(password) <= 8 && a >= 2 ) {

         printf("You have entered a valid password");

         break;
       }
         else {
         printf("\e[2J\e[H");
         printf("Invalid Password!\nEnter password with a maximum of 8 characters and at least 2 numbers\n");           
            }    
   }while(valid > 5 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The "password" variable should be "char password[9];"  additionally, strspn() does not do what I think YOU think it does.  Perhaps you should simply count the number of characters in "password" that "isdigit()" returns a non-zero value.  After testing all characters in "password", if your digit_count is greater than or equal to 2, then it passes edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to count the num of Numbers in the string. Use a for loop to go through each letter in the string

```
int numcount=0;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
if(isdigit()) numcount+=;}
if(numcount>=2) //password is good {}
else {} //bad
```

Probably not good syntax. Havent used C in awhile but this is the idea.

Comment: This worked for me, with slightly different syntax, but this is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!